# Not Receiving Proper Subscription Messages from Pub/Sub

Tags: notifications, publish-subscribe, subscription

I am trying to retrieve subscription information from Google when I receive a Real Time Notification from Google Pub/Sub.  Google Pub/Sub is sending me subscription token in this format:

```
{"message":{"data":"REALLY LONG STRING","messageId":"468103560112704","message_id":"468103560112704","publishTime":"2019-03-18T17:19:01.444Z","publish_time":"2019-03-18T17:19:01.444Z"},"subscription":"my/pubsub/subscriptions/path"}
```

I don't believe that this is the format that a subscription token is supposed to arrive in, and when I send it to Google to retrieve information using an HTTP GET command, I get nothing, no errors and no data.  I think that it is just a generic message.  I would think that I am doing everything right because I am actually getting messages when I expect to get them during testing, I just can't do anything useful with them.  Any thoughts at all on how to get these converted to REAL messages???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one took far to long to figure out, and the solution turned out to be quite simple.  I was surprised that for two weeks, nobody at Google could find an answer to this question for me.  It turns out that this is the correct format for the Pub/Sub message. The JSON message that I was receiving from PubSub was in a VERY different format from what I was expecting based on the Google Play documentation, and basically just had a "data" field that looked like a token, but it wasn't.  I actually had to dive into the PubSub documentation deep and found an obscure note on the "data" field - it is a base64 encoded string.  If you decode the "data" field, voila!, you get a JSON string containing the subscription purchaseToken that you need to query Google Play for subcription information.

So there is a JSON message INSIDE of this JSON message, but it is base64 encoded, and you just need to decode it to get to the expected treasure inside.